# Entity Framework -- do not update field?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers, entity-framework-5

I have an entity with one field in particular, "DateUpdated" that when the entity is saved, I do not want to be updated by the data context. A trigger on the database updates that field.

Is there a data annotation or similar feature that I can use to indicate this do-not-update request to the data context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DatabaseGenerated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute like this `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`